# Pandas, populate dataframe columns for each row from array in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large Pandas Dataframe with the following structure:

```py
data = {'id': [3, 5, 9, 12], 
        'names': ["{name1,name2,name3}", "{name1,name3}", "{name1,name2}", "{name2,name1,name3}"],
        'values':["{N,Y,N}", "{N,N}", "{Y,N}", "{N,Y,Y}"]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Note that the names are not always in the same order or always all included for each `id`, however the order of the values does correspond to the names as ordered for each row.

I would like to turn this table into the following structure as efficiently as possible:

```py
data = {'id': [3, 5, 9, 12], 
        'name1': ["N", "N", "Y", "Y"],
        'name2': ["Y", " ", "N", "N"],
        'name3': ["N", "N", " ", "Y"],
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Currently I am accomplishing this with the following subroutine where I essentially go through the `df` row by row and create lists of the names and values and then add those values to new columns. This works correctly but it is very slow (estimated at ~14 hrs) since my `df` is large (~2e5 rows). And each row or `id` can have up to 194 names, i.e. `"{name1, name2, ..., name193, name194}"`.

```py
def add_name_cols(df, title_col, value_col):
    nRows = len(df)
    for index,row in df.iterrows(): # parse rows and replace characters
        title_spl = [ i for i in row[title_col].replace('{','').replace('}','').split(',') ]
        value_spl = [ i for i in row[value_col].replace('{','').replace('}','').split(',') ]
        i = 0
        for t in title_spl: # add value in correct column for this row
            print('Progress rows: {0:2.2f}%, Progress columns: {1:2.2f}%'.format(float(index)/float(nRows)*100, float(i)/float(194)*100), end='\r')
            df.loc[index,t] = value_spl[i]
            i += 1
    return df

df_new = add_name_cols(df, 'names', 'values')
df_new
```

Is there a way to accomplish this manipulation using more of Pandas' built-in methods that would expedite this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string methods and dict constructor inside list comprehension.

(i) Convert `df[['names','values']]` to a list of lists

(ii) iterate over each pair, i.e. row in `df`, and use `str.strip` and `str.split` to create pair of lists, unpack and cast to `dict` constructor

(iii) Pass the resulting list of dictionaries to `pd.DataFrame`

```
temp = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(*[x.strip('{}').split(',') for x in pair])) for pair in df[['names','values']].to_numpy().tolist()]).fillna('')
df[temp.columns] = temp
df = df.drop(['names','values'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   id name1 name2 name3
0   3     N     Y     N
1   5     N           N
2   9     Y     N      
3  12     Y     N     Y
```